# How to "kickstart" a scheduled Quartz job?

Tags: quartz.net

I use IScheduler.ScheduleJob to create a job with a ChronSchedule trigger.  It runs correctly according to its schedule and I use DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute to ensure that a long running job does not get triggered more than once at a time.  I want to pro-actively start the job at will, but still never have more than one instance of the job running at a time.  Is there a method I can use within Quartz.Net that will kickstart a job aside from a Chron trigger, while preserving the limit of only one instance of the job running at a time?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the IScheduler.TriggerJob method, which seems to do exactly what I wanted.